# Perl Format yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-dd in Excel

Tags: excel, perl

I am trying to write to an `Excel` sheet using `Excel::Writer:XLSX`.

I know that it is possible to do date time format using `write_date_time( $row, $col, $date_string, $format )`

However, `$date_string` has to be one of these formats (the T is required)

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss         # Standard format
yyyy-mm-ddT                     # No time
          Thh:mm:ss.sss         # No date
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ        # Additional Z (but not time zones)
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss             # No fractional seconds
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm                # No seconds
```

The problem is the string I have right now is in the format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the space  in your timestamps with a `T` with a regular expression. If the timestamps are consistent, that will work.

```
write_date_time( $row, $col, $date_string =~ tr/ /T/r, $format );
```

This transliterates spaces  into capital Ts `T` and returns the result instead of changing in-place.

See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators). The `/r` flag requires at least Perl 5.14.